# LiveData - Using SingleLiveEvent with Transformations

Tags: android, mvvm, android-architecture-components, android-livedata

I am now using the recent Android Architecture Components and in particular the ViewModel and LiveData.

I am in a case where the [SingleLiveEvent](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture/blob/dev-todo-mvvm-live/todoapp/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/architecture/blueprints/todoapp/SingleLiveEvent.java) suggested [here](https://medium.com/google-developers/viewmodels-and-livedata-patterns-antipatterns-21efaef74a54) is relevant, i.e. I am returning an error and I want to display an alert only once. Before emitting a value to the Activity, I need to map my error to a more appropriate object for the view. I am using a Transformation for this.

So in the end, I have a ViewModel that looks like:

```
public LiveData<ViewState> getStateForView() {
    final LiveData<NetworkState> liveState = myRepository.getState();
    return Transformations.map(liveState, myMapper::map);
}
```

Where in my repository I am using a SingleLiveEvent:

```
public LiveData<NetworkState> getState() {
    myNetworkState = new SingleLiveEvent<>();
    return myNetworkState;
}
```

This works fairly well but I notice that my event is not propagated all the time when orientation changes multiple times. When debugging, I have noticed that there is no symmetry between the observer registration and removal:

- at registration time the observer of my SingleLiveEvent is the anonymous Observer class in my SingleLiveEvent

[image: debug of registration]

- at removal time the observer to be removed from my SingleLiveEvent is a MediatorLiveData (which is actually observing the earlier anonymous class in my SingleLiveEvent)

[image: debug of removal]

What happens is that my initial observer is never removed from the observers of the SingleLiveEvent (so if orientation changes multiple times my SingleLiveEvent has multiple observers).

I cannot figure out why this is not the same observer at removal time. When reproducing it without a Transformation step, there is no such issue.

Does anyone have a hint about this behaviour? Are SingleLiveEvent (not part of the framework) and Transformations not supposed to work together?

Comment: Check this. https://stackoverflow.com/a/55212795/9381524     Consider to use EventWrapper.

Answer (score 3):

I have found out that this is due to the fact that `Transformations` use a `MediatorLiveData`, which uses the `SingleLiveEvent` as a referenced source. This source is used for registration and removal of itself as an observer.

However, the `SingleLiveEvent` introduces an intermediate observer at registration time. The `SingleLiveEvent` references this intermediate observer and does not know about the `MediatorLiveData`.

At removal time, the `MediatorLiveData` tries to unregister itself as an observer from the `SingleLiveEvent`. Since the `SingleLiveEvent` does not know about it, it keeps the intermediate observer.

In the end, the process is not symmetrical and over time (as the user turns the phone), the `SingleLiveEvent` has more and more observers.

I don't know if I missed something or if the `MediatorLiveData` is not to be used with `SingleLiveEvent`, but I found a solution for my specific problem.

I added a reference to the intermediate observer in the `SingleLiveEvent` and I have overriden its `removeObserver()` method to remove the intermediate observer and not (only) the `MediatorLiveData`. I am not so confident about this solution because I am not familiar with the internals of the `LiveData`. In  particular, this solution would only work if the `SingleLiveEvent` is used only with `MediatorLiveData` as observers (i.e. not if the Activity observes the `SingleLiveEvent`), and only if there is a single observer (which makes sense in the case of a `SingleLiveEvent`). There might be other limitations.

Here is the code I added to remove the right observer (`singleLiveEventIntermediateObserver` is the anonymous `Observer` instantiated in the `observe()` method):

```
@Override
public void removeObserver(@NonNull Observer<T> observer) {
    super.removeObserver(observer);
    if (this.singleLiveEventIntermediateObserver != null) {
        super.removeObserver(this.singleLiveEventIntermediateObserver);
    }
}
```