# Why observe MutableLiveData triggers twice without postValue?

Tags: android, android-livedata

I want to add file path to Db and when a file already exists in DB show a Toast message. In ViewModel class:

```
public void addFile(SharedFile file) {
    DefaultExecutorSupplier.getInstance().forBackgroundTasks()
            .execute(() -> {
                long result = fileRepository.insert(file);
                insertResult.postValue(result);
            }
    );
}

public MutableLiveData<Long> getInsertResult() {
    return insertResult;
}
```

and in the Fragment `onViewCreated`:

```
    viewModel.getInsertResult().observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), aLong -> {
        if (aLong == -1) {
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), getString(R.string.already_exist_file), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
```

It works and when I add a repetitive file it Toasts the message, but the problem is when I open another fragment and back to the current fragment it again Toasts message.

Comment: Because it works like a BehaviorRelay and not a PublishRelay, therefore you should not expect it to work as a PublishRelay. AKA it will emit the last held value when you call `observe`.

Comment: It depends on the way how to move between the fragments ... you can `initialize the viewModel` in the activity and pass on the viewmodel instance via `onAttachFragment(..)`. Then this scenario might not happen even if u call observe multiple times on the `same` `liveData`

Answer (score 1):

This is because when (re)subscribing to a LiveData you always receive the value that was emitted last. See [here under Always up to date data](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/livedata). Some ways around this are discussed here: [Android LiveData prevent receive the last value on observe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49832787/android-livedata-prevent-receive-the-last-value-on-observe)