# Observer is called multiple times when DialogFragment is opened with screen rotation changes

Tags: android, kotlin, android-livedata, mutablelivedata

I have an activity that implements an observer inside the OnCreate for a MutableLiveData variable that is in a ViewModel.

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    ...
    subscribeDialogFragmentManualInput()
}

private fun subscribeDialogFragmentManualInput() {
    this.sharedViewModel.inputBarcode.observe(this) { inputValue ->
        postInput(inputValue)
    }
}
```

My activity is always in landscape mode (default in Manifest) and when a button is pressed a DialogFragment is opened and it changes the rotation to Portrait, when it is closed the activity returns to Landscape mode.

```
private fun showInvoiceInputDialog() {
    val inputDialog = InvoiceInputDialogFragment
    val transaction = supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
    inputDialog.show(transaction, InvoiceInputDialogFragment.TAG)
}
```

```
class InvoiceInputDialogFragment : DialogFragment() {

    lateinit var binding: DialogFragmentInvoiceInputBinding
    private val sharedViewModel by sharedViewModel<ManualInvoiceInputViewModel>()
    private var invoiceInput: String = ""
...


    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {
        setStyle(
            STYLE_NORMAL,
            R.style.FullScreenDialog
        )

        binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(
            inflater,
            R.layout.dialog_fragment_invoice_input,
            container,
            false
        )

        return binding.root
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        ...

        activity?.requestedOrientation = ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT

        setViews()
    }

    override fun onDismiss(dialog: DialogInterface) {
        super.onDismiss(dialog)

        activity?.requestedOrientation = ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE
        if(invoiceInput.isNotEmpty()) {
            sharedViewModel.sendInputInvoice(invoiceInput)
        }
    }

    private fun setViews() {
        binding.btConfirmInput.setOnClickListener {
            invoiceInput = binding.scannerManualInput.text
            dismiss()
        }
    }
}
```

This flow makes the observer triggered multiple times making my app having and undesirable comportment because the livedata result open a dialog and it is displayed multiple times.

I want to call `postInput` method only one time after DialogFragment is closed.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you help to attach the code for `sharedViewModel.inputBarcode.postValue()` or `sharedViewModel.inputBarcode.setValue()` as well? and also make sure those was not triggered multiple times

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`LiveData` is by default setup in near circular logic. This raises some problems when the view updates `LiveData` the `LiveData` will then want to update the view again, creating an infinite loop. Although you are doing it indirectly by provoking the `Android Lifecycle` to re-create your `Activity` and when its re-created it attaches another observer thus re-emitting the old value.

You have 2 options:

Save the fact that the dialog was already called in the savedInstanceState `Bundle`

```
overide fun onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState : Bundle?) {
// Save the user's current game state
 savedInstanceState.putBoolean("dialogCausedRecreate", dialogWasCreated);
 super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState); 
} 

//in onCreate
this.sharedViewModel.inputBarcode.observe(this) { inputValue ->
    if(!savedInstanceState.getBoolean("dialogCausedRecreate",false)){
         postInput(inputValue)
    }
}
```

OR

Create a new wrapper class that can keeps track if its been emitted.
Here is an example
[LiveData prevent receive the last value when start observing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49832787/livedata-prevent-receive-the-last-value-when-start-observing)

The accepted answer will have you wrap your barcode inside an Event class and that will allow you to tell if it already been emitted previously.

Comment: Thanks, I decided to use a wrapper class and it's working